# File upload in dropzone is working even when clickable is false

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js

I am initializing a dropzone element and based on some parameters I should toggle the clickable function so that some users are able to upload the files and some are not.
I am setting the value of the `clickable` function to `false` but still the element is clickable.
How can I rectify this error?

```
function initializeAttachmentsDropzone(){
    Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
    // Dropzone stuff
    myDropzone = new Dropzone("div#attachments", { url: "/app/attachments/",
                        paramName: "attachments",
                        // maxFiles: 10,
                        uploadMultiple: true,
                        addRemoveLinks: true,
                        autoProcessQueue: false,
                        parallelUploads: 10,
                        maxFilesize: 2000,
                        thumbnailHeight: 250,
                        thumbnailWidth: 250,
                        dictRemoveFileConfirmation: "Are you sure you want to delete this file?",
                        accept: function(file, done) {
                          if (file.size == 0) {
                            done("Empty files will not be uploaded.");
                          }
                          else { done(); }
                        },
                        headers: {
                            "X-CSRFToken": csrftoken
                        },
                        init: function(){
                            this.removeAllFiles();

                        }
    });
    myDropzone.on("removedfile", deleteAttachment);
}




function disableFieldsOnUpdate(){
    if ($("#page_details").val()){
        $(".dev-page").prop("disabled", true);
        myDropzone.options.clickable = false;
    }
    else {
        $(".dev-page").prop("disabled", false);
        myDropzone.options.clickable = true;
    }
}


$(document).ready(function(){
    initializeAttachmentsDropzone();
    disableFieldsOnUpdate();
});
```

Here in the browser when I check the value of `clickable` it is `false` but even then I am able to click the attachments element. How can I toggle the functionality as per the requirement?

**EDIT**

The only solution that worked for me is as below:

```
let isRemoveEnabledInAttachments;

function getRemoveEnabled() {
    if ($("#page_details").val()){
        isRemoveEnabledInAttachments = false;
        }
    if ($("#page_details").attr("update_fields") && $("#page_details").attr("has_permission") == "True"){
        isRemoveEnabledInAttachments = true;
    }
    return isRemoveEnabledInAttachments;
}

function initializeAttachmentsDropzone(){
    Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
    // Dropzone stuff
    myDropzone = new Dropzone("div#attachments", { url: "/app/attachments/",
                        paramName: "attachments",
                        // maxFiles: 10,
                        uploadMultiple: true,
                        addRemoveLinks: true,
                        autoProcessQueue: false,
                        parallelUploads: 10,
                        maxFilesize: 2000,
                        thumbnailHeight: 250,
                        thumbnailWidth: 250,
                        dictRemoveFileConfirmation: "Are you sure you want to delete this file?",
                        accept: function(file, done) {
                          if (file.size == 0) {
                            done("Empty files will not be uploaded.");
                          }
                          else { done(); }
                        },
                        headers: {
                            "X-CSRFToken": csrftoken
                        },
                        init: function(){
                            this.removeAllFiles();
                            if (isRemoveEnabledInAttachments) {
                                this.enable();
                            } else {
                                this.disable();
                            }

                        }
    });
    myDropzone.on("removedfile", deleteAttachment);
}
```

But here even if I disable the `remove file` link is shown.

**EDIT 2**

I had to add

```
this.options.addRemoveLinks = false;
```

inside the `init` function itself. Even setting it as global variable and using `Dropzone.options.myDropzone.options` as stated in the comments did not work.

Answer (score 0):

replace your function as below:

```
    function disableFieldsOnUpdate(){
        if ($("#page_details").val()){
            $(".dz-hidden-input").prop("disabled",true);
         
        }
        else 
{
        $(".dz-hidden-input").prop("disabled",false);
        }
    }
```

Comment: In the else condition I want it to be clickable.

Comment: What is the value you get on this  : $("#page_details").val()

Comment: It is the value of id of an object.

Comment: $(".dz-hidden-input").prop("disabled",true); run this on your conslole(in brower). Itried on code pen, It works on My end. (Answer updated)

Comment: This works in browser but it is not working when I put it in js file. I have edited the question. The only solution that is working for me. But still it is showing the remove links even after disabling.

Comment: The thing is I am only able to change from `init`. Not able to edit any options from other functions. If I do the same in console then it is working fine.

Comment: put myDropzone  as global, then update the properties whenenver you need. Dropzone.options.myDropzone.options.addRemoveLinks=false;

Comment: Even that did not work. I add to add it into `init` function.